# Spring statemachine Persist Statecontext

Tags: persist, spring-statemachine

In the reference documentation there is a sample for perstisting a statemachine:

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-statemachine/1.0.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#statemachine-recipes-persist

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-statemachine/1.0.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#statemachine-examples-persist

Does anybody know, if there is a way to perstist also the stateContext?

Thanks Fredy

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to use an actual Reference ;-o -> http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-statemachine/1.1.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#sm-persist

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use new statemachine 1.1.0.RELEASE and then use new built-in capability 
[StateMachinePersister](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-statemachine/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/sm-persist.html#sm-persist-statemachinepersister). The example uses InMemoryStateMachinePersist.